# How to remove the divide between table rows in e-mail shot?

Tags: html, email, html-email, mailchimp

I recently mocked up an e-mail marketing (mail chimp) e-mail in Photoshop, and exported it into HTML (using tables and inline styles (unfortunately) so that it appears correctly in all/most e-mail clients.

However, after sending myself a test e-mail to see how it appears in my Gmail account, I can see there is a white dividing line between each row of my table, which I cannot seem to remove or find when I inspect it in Google Chrome.

Can anybody tell me how to remove these dividers?
My full HTML can found at http://pastebin.com/gJWJGEak#
A screenshot of how the email is currently appearing can be found at http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/346/screenshotvg.png

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem. It has nothing  to do with borders, but with the size of the text inside the cells.

Your text expands too much and it causes the containing cells to expand.
If you reduce the text size or the margin of the paragraphs you'll achieve the desired result.

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply gjsduarte, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue when I make the font much smaller. The paragraphs are inside the table cells and have enough room so that they don't stretch the table cells. I haven't come across this before, very strange!

Answer (score 0):

All of your images need to be explicitly `style="display:block;"`.

And just a heads up, background images won't work in Outlook 2007 and 2010.