# How do I remove white lines between table rows send in an email?

Tags: html, css, email

I have the following table that's being used to group images for html email content

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="/SaveDateHeader.png" style="border: none;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;text-transform: capitalize;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><img src="/body.png" style="border: none;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;text-transform: capitalize;" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/leftfooter.png" style="border: none;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;text-transform: capitalize;" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/rightfooter.png" style="border: none;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;text-transform: capitalize;" />
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

It looks fine in outlook and in mobile, but when I view it on gmail.com spaces appear between the table rows.

My first approach was to use floating divs, but that had a different set of issues when being viewed on mobile devices.

I found this questions, but none of the advice worked for me. [How to remove the divide between table rows in e-mail shot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560885/how-to-remove-the-divide-between-table-rows-in-e-mail-shot)

Comment: Might be an image related problem and not a table related problem.

Comment: I'll play around with the images to see if I can get it any better.  However, using developer tools, I was able to determine that the gap is not caused by the images.  I inspected each element, and it appears that it's either the cells or the rows.  Since no gap appears between the two cells in the last row, I assume it's the row.  But I'm fairly certain that the images are not causing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To all of your images, add `"display: block;"`. I suspect it actually is an image problem. Also, you must do table-based layout in emailers. Do not try to use modern strategies! Tables and inline styles for everything. Also, try collapsing some of your white space.

Comment: I'm not sure which one did it, but I moved all the styles inline, changed the display to block and removed all whitespace and line breaks.  And it worked.  Thanks!